# possible to run Dell monitors as a single monitor with a MBA 2013

Tags: macbook-pro

I do software development and would like to run two Dell U2414H's in portrait mode as a single screen. Is this possible with a MBA 2013? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Air will require a Dual-link DVI output using Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter to connect to the two monitors (so the monitors need DVI cables/connectors) and as long as the **combined** resolution of the displays is no more than 2500 x 1600 then it will work as that is the max resolution of an external display with this Mac.

If the combined Max resolution of these displays is higher than 2500 x 1600 it may well support both but you won't get the maximum resolution out of the displays.

Comment: that sounds like an ugly and expensive solution ..... ugh...

Comment: would a modern mac mini be able to achieve this better?

Comment: if you go to Apple support they have the specifications for **all** Macs. That is where I got the info for the MacBook Air.

Comment: thx - so just so I understand the dual-link dvi is between the two monitors not the between computer and monitor, right?

Comment: also, do you have any experience with the Matrox DualHeadToGo?

Comment: I **believe** that that adapter/cable is so you can use two monitors on one thunderbolt port. Verify that before buying anything. No experience with that Matrox device.